# regex to extract what preceds equal

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to define a regex in php to extract words but i didn't succeed... 
My string is always in this format: "toto=on test=on azerty=on gogo=on" 
what I would like to do is to get in an array the values toto, test,azerty and gogo. Can someone help ?

that's what i tried so far : `/([^\s]|[w]*?=)/`

Comment: Well, `w` only matches `w`. `[^\s]` matches any char that is not whitespace. Why did you expect this pattern to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple

```
preg_match_all("/(\w*)=/", "toto=on test=on azerty=on gogo=on", $output_array)[1];
```

It will get all word before "=", the parentheses is for defining a group and put in key "1" , "\w" is for a letter and "*" is for "many"

or You can improve that and use like that

```
preg_match_all("/(\w*)=on/", "toto=on test=on azerty=on gogo=on", $output_array)[1];
```

So will get only parameters "on", if you have "toto=on test=on azerty=on gogo=on toff=off", the string "toff" dont will appear

I like to use this link http://www.phpliveregex.com/ , so you can try regex and responses in PHP

Answer (score 2):

A different approach to this question would be this way

```
<?php

$str = "toto=on test=on azerty=on gogo=on";
$res = str_replace("=on","", $str);
$array = explode(" ", $res);
print_r($array); //Array ( [0] => toto [1] => test [2] => azerty [3] => gogo )

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure! Here's a working regex: https://regex101.com/r/IWP1Mh/1

And here's the working code: https://3v4l.org/QQZj5

```
<?php

$regex = '#(?<names>\w*)=\w*#';
$string = 'toto=on test=on azerty=on gogo=on';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
$names = $matches['names'];
var_dump($names);
```

Which outputs:

```
array(4) { 
[0]=> string(4) "toto" 
[1]=> string(4) "test" 
[2]=> string(6) "azerty" 
[3]=> string(4) "gogo" 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can juse use `explode()`:

```
$str = 'toto=on test=on azerty=on gogo=on';
$words = array_map(function($item){ return substr($item, 0, -3); }, explode(' ', $str));
```